# C++ builderのプロジェクトファイル構成について

Tags: c++

現在、15年ほど前にBorland C++ Builder6で作成されたプロジェクトファイルの内容を、最近のembarcaderoのC++ Builder 10.3 Communityにソースコードを移してビルドしたいと思っています。

ただ、やはりエラーが多数でてこれからいろいろと手を付けていこうとおもっております。

あまりC++ BuiderなどのIDEを使ったことがないため、色々な点で不明な点・疑問が出ていますが、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

渡されているプロジェクトファイルを眺めていると

・Debug.cpp
・DevInfo.cpp
・Main.cpp
・ServerSetup.cpp
・Trace.cpp

だいたいこの5つの種類のcppファイルとそれに関連するhファイルやdfmファイルであることに気づきました。

これは単純に、Cpp Builderのからのフォームプロジェクトを作成した時のUnit.cppができている時のように、フォーム画面が5つあるものをこのプロジェクトに属していると考えれば良いのでしょうか？
どうぞ、ご教示の程よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

C++Builderはあんまり触ってないので外してるかもですが、
同名のdfm、cpp、hの3ファイルで1個のフォーム
同名のcpp、hの2ファイルで1個のユニットになっていると思います。
drcファイルは多言語設定時の翻訳データ
bprはプロジェクトファイルになるかと思います。
（但し、C++Builderはプロジェクトの移行を行うとトラブル事が多い印象があるので新規プロジェクトに上記のファイルを追加する形で移行する方が良い気がします。）

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。助かります。

Answer (score 0):

Borland C++ Builder6からC++ Builder 10.3 Communityですと文字列(string)の扱いが変わっていると思います。
Builder6ではAnsiStringを使っていたと思いますが、Builder 10.3ではUnicodeStringがデフォルトになっていると思います。
このあたりで、コンパイルエラーになることがあります。